# Association miner of string Java

Tags: java

I am doing project on sentiment analysis of product reviews of amazon, I have to do association mining of my nouns in a sentence as a set with nouns of other sentences to generate my user specific feature, i.e features of products which are talked by customers, which will be mostly nouns, (as for now, future pronoun can also be considered).

But my question is can somebody provide link to some java jar file of association mining of **string**? I googled but I was getting only of integers. In the paper I was implementing they association miner was based on **Apriori algorithm** . Help is really appreciated, thanks in advance for reading my problem.

Comment: Since you're asking for a `.jar` file for Java and for some algorithm, then what caused you to ask here, instead of asking at Stack Overflow? This is a perfectly valid question for that site, as I suppose.